# Link list with a vector pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, data-structures

I'm trying to build a tree for my data structure course using struct of vectors to connect the nodes.
here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    vector<node> *next;
    string val;
    int tagid;
};

int main()
{
    string operation;
    node *head=new node;
    head->next->resize(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I tried to modify the first element's pointer with this code

```
head->next[0]=NULL;
```

The compiler gives me the error `no match for ‘operator=’`. How can I write it correct to be able to modify it's elements?

Comment: i dont get why `next` is `vector<node>*` and not a `vector<node*>`; and `head->next` is not initialized, thus accessing it via index (`[]`) results in undefined behaviour (mostly worlddomination and access violation)

Comment: @Zaiborg Thanks, I changed `vector<node>*` to `vector<node*>` ,and `head->next->resize(1);` to `head->next.resize(1);` and it worked very well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Zaiborg comments, this works for me :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    vector<node*> next;
    string val;
    int tagid;
};

int main()
{
    string operation;
    node *head = new node;
    head->next.resize(1);
    head->next[0] = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with : g++ -Wall gives you no warning and no errors at the compilation.